# ASP.Net - Use C# and VB in the same Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have come into a new company to upgrade a large web application.  Yes it is a Web app not a Web site and I am using Web forms.

It is quite old and I would say poorly written.  The PM wants to have it cleaned up and ported to C#.  The issue here is that it is constantly changing and updates will still be working whilst I work on it.

The current plan is to create a new home page launcher in a new UI (c#) so that the upgrade is coming.  Rewrite certain sections at a time and release as we go.  The launcher currently actually launches new pages in a new browser window so I do think this is feasible.

However, so my question is can this be done.  I've read a number of threads that it is possible with web sites but not with web apps.  If this cant be done is there a solution where I can run my web app and launch windows in the older app.  Desirably having the two different web apps in the same solution?

Comment: What framework are you using? Is this an MVC app or a WebFroms app?

Comment: Each assembly needs to pick a language, but you have a lot of freedom regarding what can be in different assemblies.  Start refactoring the application's logic into a C# assembly and make the VB application layer as thin as possible.  The less logic that's in the application layer, the easier it will be to replace it with a new application layer.

Comment: @AdamSchiavone - I am using web forms....I have edited my question..thanks

Comment: First issue here is that a PM is telling you to "Port your code over to C#" no Architect or Senior developer would recommend this approach. What is that really buying you?  If something major needs to be done a project to rewrite the site in C# MVC is what needs to take place.  WebForms is basically legacy technology now, take a longer vision and start a new project to rewrite the site. Then tell the PM to stick to managing the project.

Comment: The reason for this is - is that the project was written by the PM many moons ago.  The team that are now in place that support a number of projects and also this one are versed in c# but mostly webforms not MVC.  Not to mention a number of third party frameworks that are already purchased from the company that are based on Webforms technology....

Comment: The main reason for the upgrade is the new UI not to port to c# that is just a benefit of the ugprade...